# sw-description file not getting sha256

Tags: yocto, bitbake, swupdate

I am trying to build a signed swu file for my board using yocto/bitbake.
The swu that gets created is signed, but the sha256 is not getting set in the sw-description file.

(below omitting some folders and files, showing relevant directory tree)

My build directory for yocto:

```
build-dir
  +conf
     bblayers.conf
     local.conf
```

In my layers dir:

```
meta-variscite-fslc
  +conf
  +dynamic-layers
      +swupdate
         +swupdate
      +var-image-swu
         +imx8mm-var-dart
            sw-description
         update.sh
      swupdate_%d.bbappend
      var-image-swu.bb
      var-image-swupdate.bb

meta-mylayer
  +conf
     layer.conf
  +recipes-blahblah
  +wic
      my-wks.in
```

By adding this to my build-dir/conf/local.conf

```
WKS_FILE = "my-wks.in"
```

I can get it to use my-wks.in (to setup the paritions like I want it to).

Then adding these to my build-dir/conf/local.conf

```
SWUPDATE_SIGNING = "RSA"
SWUPDATE_PRIVATE_KEY = "/tmp/rsakey"
SWUPDATE_IMAGES = "var-image-swupdate update.sh"
```

makes it create a swu file (var-image-swu-imx8mm-var-dart.swu)

I generated my keys like this:

```
openssl genrsa -out /tmp/rsakey
openssl rsa -in /tmp/rsakey -out /tmp/rsakey.pub -outform PEM -pubout
```

But when I look inside the swu file, I do not see sha256 for my image file. And when I try to install this swu, I get this error:

swupdate -i /var-image-swu-imx8mm-var-dart.swu --hwrevision "imx8mm-var-dart:1.0" --key /rsakey.pub

```
ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR core/parser.c : check_missing_hash : 76 : Hash not set for var-image-swupdate-imx8mm-var-dart.tar.gz Type archive                          
[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR core/swupdate.c : install_from_file : 335 : failed to parse sw-description!
```

So obviously sha256 hash is missing, how do I get it to add the hash in my sw-description file?

I tried to follow [the steps here](https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/building-with-yocto.html) but I don't understand what to do to make it update my sw-description file with the sha256 hashes.

Note that I can manually edit sw-description file here

```
meta-variscite-fslc
  +conf
  +dynamic-layers
      +swupdate
         +swupdate
      +var-image-swu
         +imx8mm-var-dart
            sw-description
```

and add the sha256 hashes myself, then the swu that is generated successfully gets installed. But I don't want to edit the file in that layer, I need to perhaps bbappend something in my layer

Answer (score 0):

Complete steps that made update work for me:

In my layer, add files, keeping same folder structure as in the layer I am overriding:

```
meta-mylayer
  +conf
    layer.conf          # add BBFILES, see below
  +dynamic-layers
    +sw-update
      +var-image-swu
        +imx8mm-var-dar
           sw-description       # <-- file I want to replace with my own 
         update.sh               # <-- file I want to replace with my own 
      var-image-swu.bbappend    # <-- overrides the recipe   
meta-variscite-fslc
  +conf
  +dynamic-layers
    +sw-update
      +var-image-swu
        +imx8mm-var-dart
           sw-description   # <-- need to overide this file
         update.sh      # <-- need to overide this file
      var-image-swu.bb        # <--original recipe
```

var-image-swu.bbappend:

```
#
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI = " \
    file://sw-description \
    file://update.sh \
"
##
```

layer.conf:

```
#
BBFILES := "${BBFILES} ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \ 
            ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend \
            ${LAYERDIR}/dynamic-layers/*/*.bbappend"    # <-- add this path to search for bbappend files
##
```

my sw-description file:

```
software =
{
    version = "0.1.0";

    imx8mm-var-dart = {
        hardware-compatibility: [ "1.0" ];

        files: (
            {
                filename = "var-image-swupdate-imx8mm-var-dart.tar.gz";
                type = "archive";
                compressed = true;
                device = "/dev/update";
                filesystem = "ext4";
                preserve-attributes = true;
                sha256 = "@var-image-swupdate-imx8mm-var-dart.tar.gz";      # <-- add this line
                path = "/";
            }
        )

        scripts: (
            {
                filename = "update.sh";
                type = "shellscript";
                sha256 = "@update.sh";                      # <-- add this line
            }
        );
    };
}
#
```

build/conf/local.conf

```
#
WKS_FILE = "nextgen.wks.in"
SWUPDATE_SIGNING = "RSA"
SWUPDATE_PRIVATE_KEY = "/tmp/rsakey"        # <-- see below for genertation of private key
SWUPDATE_IMAGES = "var-image-swupdate-imx8mm-var-dart update.sh sw-description.sig" # <-- these 3 files are in the swu payload, hashes will get gernated and @filename will be replaced with hash
#
```

On the target device, to update:

```
swupdate -v -i /var-image-swu-imx8mm-var-dart.swu --hwrevision "imx8mm-var-dart:1.0" --key /rsakey.pub
```

(after copying swu file and public key to the / dir)

Keys were generated on host machine like this

```
openssl genrsa -out /tmp/rsakey
openssl rsa -in /tmp/rsakey -out /tmp/rsakey.pub -outform PEM -pubout
```

then public key was scp'ed over to the target device

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `sha265` attribute yourself to the `sw-description` file with the following syntax:

`sha256 = "@artifact-file-name";`

See also:
https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/building-with-yocto.html#automatic-sha256-in-sw-description